# Variance of nominal variable?

Tags: variance, categorical-data

Note that the only measure of location in nominal variable is mode.

Is there also any measure of variance?
Obviously, some nominal features are more different than other (color of eyes vs. presence of some rare disease).

Answer (score 4):

There is no measure of the *variance* exactly in nominal data. There are measures of diffusion. [Kader](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v15n2/kader.pdf) provides a good discussion.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, it looks like a nice article. So diffusion is something like variance in nomimal variables.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no consensus on terminology in this field.

Comment: Another question can be "What are descriptive characteristics of nominal variables?" Can we find any other measure except of mode and diffusion? Maybe entropy, but it is similar concept as diffusion.

Comment: There are lots of variations on similar themes for diffusion, variation (whatever you want to call it). 

The standard measure of such variables is, of course, the frequency table. There's no measure of "central tendency" because there is no center.